# Jquery - Loading Animation Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display a loading image after an AJAX call has been made.

Currently I have the following Javascript code:

```
window.onload = function(){

var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif";

function getCategories(){
    $.ajax({
        url: //url here,
        dataType:'jsonp',           
        success: function(data){

            //code here

        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                alert:('There was a problem with the server');
            }
        }

    }); 
}



$(document).ajaxStart(function(){   
    alert('here');
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "id1";
    document.getElementById('id1').appendChild(img);
    document.body.appendChild(div);

}).ajaxStop(function(){
    var element = document.getElementById('id1');
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

});
```

However, I am finding that the code is not even getting to the ajaxStart function as the alert is not appearing... I have tried other methods (eg: [How to show loading spinner in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery)) to try and get this working but have not been successful as of yet...

Would anyone be able to help with this please?

Thank you.

Comment: Any error on the console?

Comment: Really sorry... but I actually did declare the function correctly. I made a mistake when copying the code over...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution here ([$(document).ajaxstart not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376819/document-ajaxstart-not-firing))

It seems that ajaxStart only works when `XMLHttpRequest` is used. If you use JSONP, `XMLHttpRequest` isn't used. Rather, it inserts a `<script>` tag to achieve this goal.

I simply used the workaround suggested in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

You are more than likely getting an error for Unexpected Token, since you are declaring a function incorrectly.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

You need to declare a function with either:

```
function getCategories () { }
```

Or:

```
var getCategories = function () { };
```